# Dynamic query - to be updated weekly - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query based on user's uploaded information, it is basically a weekly file with employee stats.
Thing is, query needs to update itself weekly (once the user has loaded new week info) to add new week's data. For example:

[image]

On that example, once Week 7 hits and the user loads info for it...a new column (week7 column) should be added.

I already have an static query but this would mean that I would have to add new parts to it every week.
Any suggestion?
(I'm thinking on looping it via PL/SQL pulling the max week number but...not sure how to translate that into a report view)

Edit:
This query would be based on a table I created myself with a process that will replace all existent data with new one every week via CSV file upload.
Table sample:
[image]
(number on Week column tells us if an employee has completed activities on that specific week)

```
EMPLOYEE    WEEK
Dana        1
Filipe      2
hannah      2
hannah      3
jonh        1
jonh        4
```

Thanks

Comment: So for week 52, There should be 52 columns?

Comment: yes! correct. The idea is to have one column per week (52 being the last one as you assumed)

Comment: Is this your original DB design, Or you have stored data diferently and you are getting this data through a query? Please post some sample data from your table also?

Comment: Please post the sample data as text, not as image.

Comment: even 53 weeks :)  ( 52 x 7 = 364 < 365 or 366 )

Comment: Does not look like a smart design. Stupid question, what happens when one year passed by? Start again with 2 columns only? Replace data? Some years have 52 weeks, some have 53 weeks - depending on which definition you use for "week". How do you like to handle this?

Comment: Yes, so basically once we start a new year user-csv-input will only have 1 week and everything previous year related will be removed

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find local help, created a function to create my query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function my_function
   RETURN varchar2

IS

v_stmt varchar2(5000);
v_my_week number;

begin

v_stmt :='with data_1 as(
select distinct
       Rep
  from My_table
  order by 1
)' ;

for i in (select distinct week from My_table ) loop

    v_stmt := v_stmt || ', week_'|| i.week || ' as(
select 
Rep,
count(unique_j) unique_'|| i.week ||
'
from My_table
where week = ' || i.week || ' 
group by week, Rep
)';

end loop; 

v_stmt := v_stmt || ' select
b.Rep';

for i in (select distinct week from My_table) loop
    v_stmt := v_stmt || ', unique_'|| i.week || ' as as Week_' || i.week ;
end loop; 
    v_stmt := v_stmt || ' from data_1 b';
for i in (select distinct week from My_table) loop
    v_stmt := v_stmt || ' left join week_'|| i.week || ' wk'|| i.week || ' on 
wk'||i.week ||'.Rep = b.Rep';

end loop;

return v_stmt;
 
end;
```

Thank you all